# How to write multiple sheets in Excel using TQExport4Xlsx Delphi component

Tags: excel, delphi, export

I am using ***TQExport4Xlsx*** component for writing **Excel files** from `dataset`. I am facing difficulty in writing different sheets in Excel files. It works file for single sheet. I don't know how to write in multiple sheets. Below is my `code`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
procedure TfrmXLSExport.btnExportClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Export4Xlsx.ExportSource:= esDataSet;
  Export4Xlsx.FileName:= ChangeFileExt(FileName, '.xlsx');
  Export4Xlsx.SheetName:= TableName;
  Export4Xlsx.Execute;
end
```

Previously I can do it by ***TQExport4Xls*** component (foe excel 2003) with "Sheets" `array` `property`. But in ***TQExport4Xlsx*** the `property` is omitted and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you asked the provider of TQExport4Xlsx? You do have a registered version of the component, don't you?

Comment: If you have a licensed version of the component, you should have support available from EMS. You should also have the source code for the unit.

Comment: Response from EMS:   Dear Reza,

Thank you for using our components.

TSMExportToXlsx does not have sunch functionality. You can make sure in it opening component editor in design time and right-clicking it. It does not have a sheets collection. We are going to add the possibility to export to several XLSX sheets in one of the further versions of the component.

If you have more questions, please do not hesitate to contact us.